# D3.js Bullet Graph - how to output ranges / x-axis values in precentage(n%) rather than in values only (n)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[ http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/bullet.html ] is D3.js Bullet Graph example. here i want to output  values x-axis in percentage like.
In 1st chart "Revenue":

0% , 50% , 150% , 200% , 250% , 300%
instead of 
0 , 50 , 150 , 200 , 250 , 300

Answer (score 1):

put this towards the bottom of the d3.json() call

```
//axis label format
svg.selectAll("g.tick").select('text').text(function (t) {
      return t*10 + "%";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it adequate to simply multiple the magnitude by 10 and then concatenate a "%" character?

My Best,

Frank